# Why can we control our breath rate but not our heart rate?

Tags: evolution, physiology, neuroscience, cardiology

Even though we cannot survive for more than few minutes if we stop breathing or if our heart stops, why is it so that our heart beat is controlled involuntarily while breathing can be voluntarily controlled to a certain extent. I just noticed that blinking of eyes also falls in this category; though we involuntarily blink and our eyelids close involuntarily in bright light, there is still voluntary modulation. What kind of evolutionary changes and natural selection could have led to these kind of voluntary modulations i.e. cortical control over these processes?

Comment: Perhaps to make tasks like eating and speaking possible. Note that you cannot voluntarily stop breathing indefinitely.

Comment: You already know why these processes cannot be voluntary. There is some level of voluntary control on breathing but it is overall involuntary. So if that is your question then you should note what @canadianer said.

Comment: evolution does not have consciousness or will. It does not make choices. Living beings are formed through mutations, natural selection,genetic drift etc.

Comment: @WYSIWYG involuntary and unconsiously doing something is different.

Comment: @DivyaPrakash they more or less mean the same. Moreover I never mentioned the word "unconscious".

Comment: Many unconsious activity like walking, writing, understanding and interpreting language are possible even though none of them are quite certainly involuntary action

Comment: @canadianer while eating and speaking breathing could also have been stopped involuntarily. There is no reason for making it voluntary to eat and speak.

Comment: @DivyaPrakash There is no debate here about subconscious control of voluntary activities. You still have to clarify your question. Plus your above comment to canadianer just sounds philisophical and not scientific.

Comment: I specifically want the answer in terms of certain evolutionary advantages if possible.

Comment: @DivyaPrakash Evolutionary advantage of what?? Little voluntary control on breathing or heart beat being involuntary. I am sure you know why that latter is advantageous.

Comment: @WYSIWYG Little voluntary control on breathing, I guess. As for the advantageousness of latter I am going to research more about what could happen if heart beat was made voluntary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23254/discussion-between-divya-prakash-and-wysiwyg).